# RequestFactory with GWT: unable to store entities

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore, requestfactory

I m creating a school project where I need to deploy an application connected with an native android app and both of them to share the same entities on Google App Engine Datastore. I followed all the instructions described by official tutorial by Google (https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideRequestFactory) but unfortunately I cannot store any entities on datastore in development mode. I m trying for weeks to configure properly the requestfactory with no success.

Below are the most important classes of my requestfactory in my project: (I added all the appropriate tags in the xml files according the google tutorial)

Here is one of my entities:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import unipiWeb.server.EMF;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.GeoPt;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory;

@Entity
public class Store{
        
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private Date dueDate;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String description;
    private long userId;
    private String country;
    
    
    private GeoPt geopt;
    
    Blob image;

    public Store(){
        
    }
    
    public Store(String name, Blob image){
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }
    
    public Store(String name, Blob image, String country){
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.country = country;
    }
    
    /*
     * Getters and Setters
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
        public Date getDueDate() {
        return dueDate;
    }

    public void setDueDate(Date dueDate) {
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public GeoPt getGeopt() {
        return geopt;
    }

    public void setGeopt(GeoPt geopt) {
        this.geopt = geopt;
    }

    public String getCountry(){
        return country;
    }
    
    public void setCountry(String country){
        this.country = country;
    }
    
    public Blob getImage(){
        return image;
    }
    
    public void setImage(Blob image){
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Store [dueDate=");
        builder.append(dueDate);
        builder.append(", name=");
        builder.append(name);
        builder.append(", description=");
        builder.append(description);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
        
    }
}
```

The EntityProxy:

```
import java.util.Date;

import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.EntityProxy;
import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.ProxyForName;

@ProxyForName(value = "unipiWeb.server.entities.Store", locator = "unipiWeb.server.entities.StoreLocator")
public interface StoreProxy extends EntityProxy {

    Long getId();

    String getName();

    void setName(String name);

    Date getDueDate();

    void setDueDate(Date dueDate);

    String getEmail();

    void setEmail(String email);

    String getDescription();

    void setDescription(String description);

    String getAddress();

    void setAddress(String address);

    long getUserId();

    void setUserId(long userId);

    String getCountry();

    void setCountry(String country);

}
```

The Service for this entity:

```
import java.util.List;

import unipiWeb.server.DataStore;
import unipiWeb.server.entities.Store;
import unipiWeb.annotation.ServiceMethod;

public class AppService {
    
    DataStore db = new DataStore();
    @ServiceMethod
    public Store createStore() {
        return db.update(new Store());
    }

    @ServiceMethod
    public Store readStore(Long id) {
        return db.find(id);
    }

    @ServiceMethod
    public Store updateStore(Store store) {
        store.setEmail(DataStore.getUserEmail());
        return db.update(store);
    }

    @ServiceMethod
    public void deleteStore(Store store) {
        db.delete(store.getId());
    }

    @ServiceMethod
    public List<Store> queryStores() {
        return db.findAll();
    }
    

}
```

The entityLocator:

```
import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.Locator;


public class StoreLocator extends Locator<Store, Void> {

    @Override
    public Store create(Class<? extends Store> clazz) {
        return new Store();
    }

    @Override
    public Store find(Class<? extends Store> clazz, Void id) {
        return create(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Store> getDomainType() {
        return Store.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Void getId(Store domainObject) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Void> getIdType() {
        return Void.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getVersion(Store domainObject) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

This is the RequestContext subclass:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.Request;
import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestContext;
import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.ServiceName;

@ServiceName(value = "unipiWeb.server.services.AppService", locator = "unipiWeb.server.services.AppServiceLocator")
public interface AppRequest extends RequestContext {
        
    Request<StoreProxy> createStore();
    
    Request<StoreProxy> readStore(Long id);
    
    Request<StoreProxy> updateStore(StoreProxy store);
        
    Request<Void> deleteStore(StoreProxy store);
    
    Request<List<StoreProxy>> queryStores();

}
```

And the requestfactory subclass:

```
import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestFactory;


public interface AppRequestFactory extends RequestFactory {
    
    AppRequest appRequest();

}
```

And this is the error appears every time I try to store a new entity. (The project debugs with no error at all)

```
17:23:53.411 [ERROR] [unipiweb] Uncaught exception escaped

com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.StringQuoter.createSplittable(StringQuoter.java:58)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.&lt;init&gt;(AbstractAutoBean.java:71)
    at unipiWeb.client.requestfactory.StoreProxyAutoBean_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_EntityProxyCategory_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_ValueProxyCategory_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_BaseProxyCategory.&lt;init&gt;(StoreProxyAutoBean_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_EntityProxyCategory_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_ValueProxyCategory_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_BaseProxyCategory.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:105)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.gwt.client.impl.JsniCreatorMap$.invoke$(JsniCreatorMap.java)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.gwt.client.impl.JsniCreatorMap$.create$(JsniCreatorMap.java:46)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.gwt.client.impl.AbstractAutoBeanFactory.create(AbstractAutoBeanFactory.java:38)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext.createProxy(AbstractRequestContext.java:688)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext.create(AbstractRequestContext.java:497)
    at unipiWeb.client.widgets.StoreWidget$4.onClick(StoreWidget.java:188)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: null
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader$MultiParentClassLoader.findClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:365)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.StringQuoter.createSplittable(StringQuoter.java:58)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.&lt;init&gt;(AbstractAutoBean.java:71)
    at unipiWeb.client.requestfactory.StoreProxyAutoBean_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_EntityProxyCategory_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_ValueProxyCategory_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_BaseProxyCategory.&lt;init&gt;(StoreProxyAutoBean_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_EntityProxyCategory_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_ValueProxyCategory_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_BaseProxyCategory.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:105)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.gwt.client.impl.JsniCreatorMap$.invoke$(JsniCreatorMap.java)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.gwt.client.impl.JsniCreatorMap$.create$(JsniCreatorMap.java:46)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.gwt.client.impl.AbstractAutoBeanFactory.create(AbstractAutoBeanFactory.java:38)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext.createProxy(AbstractRequestContext.java:688)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext.create(AbstractRequestContext.java:497)
    at unipiWeb.client.widgets.StoreWidget$4.onClick(StoreWidget.java:188)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Any Instructions or suggestions are welcome!!**
Thank You!!!

Answer (score 3):

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException

Make sure the org.json jar is on your classpath (usually called `json.jar`). You can add this jar directly, or use another jar which contains these classes. You can get this from maven as org.json:json:20090211 or from http://www.json.org/java/index.html.

According to https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideRequestFactory, the `requestfactory-server.jar` jar should contain these classes, though other users have reported issues with this (see discussion at https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/76btyDIat7k/discussion) - they suggest that you try the `gwt-servlet-deps.jar` jar if the other doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately I just tried your suggestion but nothing happened! :-(

Comment: What do you have on the classpath? If this is in Eclipse, the project classpath isn't the only thing to matter, but the Run Configuration can have different classpath elements, so after you change the project's classpath, you need to update the Run Config. Additionally, the jar needs to be in the `WEB-INF/lib/` directory (unless using maven, then it should be there automatically). More details (how you are running this, what is on the classpath, etc) will give enough information to help.